# Aptana, CSS editor (configuration)

Tags: css, configuration, ide, editor, aptana

Can you please tell how can I configure Aptana, to autocomplete CSS after automatically adding the colon as well add a space (very inconvenient to manually enter each time).

[image]
→
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using [Aptana Studio 3](http://www.aptana.com/products/studio3), and it seems to do exactly what you want already. For example, it autocompleted background, the colon as well as the space, and then recommended values. [See Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DeCwO.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Apparently in *Aptana Studio 3* there is multiple CSS editors which might cause confusion, to me the default editor was not even showing syntax coloring.

To change editor for individual file right click the CSS file in Project Explorer, Choose *Open With* -> *CSS Editor* (or try other editors too).

To change CSS editor globally go to *Preferences -> General -> Editors -> File Associations*.

Unfortunately because there is *three* CSS editors in my Aptana 3 Studio, it is almost impossible to know which of these is always shown in *Preferences dialog*. If your CSS editor setting changes doesn't work, it might well be that you are configuring different editor. Sigh.

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to note: it also depends on the theme you are using. I use Aptana 3 and see absolutely no syntac highlighting using the pre-installed "Eclipse" theme, but it works great if I use "Aptana 2.x"-theme.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I fixed: rename parent folder of css from *bootstrap-3.3.6* to *bootstrap*
Then all css in boostrap will be autocomplete in html file